# wpf ListView doesn't select item on first touch

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, touch

There have been a few other posts about wpf list view not selecting item at first, but my problem appears to be different.
I have a list view control. The first time I click on an item it works fine. However, when using the touch screen, the first time i touch something nothing happens. The second time (and forever after) everytime I touch it changes the selected item and fires the event.

The first time I touch it the list view does in fact fire the touch down, so it doesn't make sense why it wouldn't select an item. Also I have checked that it has focus

```
Action focusAction = () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    bool val = PrimarylistView.Focus();
                    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, PrimarylistView);                    
                };
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(focusAction, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

And I can visually see the column headers being highlighted after.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yea, My list view was within a scroll viewer. And there is what I believe would be considered a bug in WPF where things just feel buggy with a touch screen if the child components dont have manipulationenabled = true. Basically whenever a child some some parent up the visual tree that has manipulation enabled = true, the child that you interact with also needs to have this set to true. Not sure why.